# Primitive types value changes

Tags: java

I know that primitive types called by value(a copy of value has been sent)

My code:

```
static int a = 5;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("a= " + a);
    setA();
    System.out.println("a= " + a);  //Why is not 5?
    setA2(a);
    System.out.println("a= " + a);  //Why is not 7?
}
public static int getSeven() {
    return 7;
}

public static void setA() {
    a = 6;
}

public static void setA2(int n) {
    n = getSeven();
}
```

Output:

```
a= 5
a= 6
a= 6
```

Why other two output is `6` again?

Why a is changed?

a is not an object!

Comment: It's very unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: but what is your question?

Comment: @developerknownasInsane The question is the notation in the code marked by `//`

Comment: okay once put `a=n` in `SetA2` method..

Comment: you'll get your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second output is `6` since you set it to `6` by the preceding row (function `setA()`). `setA()` is setting a primitive outside of the function but in the class, so this is also available in `main()`.

The third output is `6` since you set the primitive `n` instead of `a`. It is a primitive so it has no reference to `a` anymore.

Comment: Nice, But why there is no compile error when we write `a=6` after a was `5`?

Comment: @user3281108 did you try my answer, ? check comment up in your post? and tell me?

Comment: @user3281108 Why would there be a compile-error upon setting `a` to another value? As long as it's not a `final` variable that is.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is global variable.

`setA()` will set the value of `a` as `6`. So every where the value of `a` will be six.

`getSeven()` is returning 7 but you are not capturing it. So `a` will remain as it is.
try it like this `a=getSeven();`

`setA2(int n)`is assigning `n` to `7` but not to `a`.
try it like this

```
public static void setA2(int n) {
    a = getSeven();
}
```

Comment: read my comment what i'm trying to say him/her..i guess you copied it :)..lol